# I get webpack not installed, but webpack --version finds webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am following [this tutorial](https://blog.nearsoftjobs.com/10-pasos-para-configurar-react-webpack-4-y-babel-7-5b4096924f23) to create a **React** project with **webpack**. Everything went smooth until step 4 `webpack --config webpack.config.js`, where I get this error:

```
webpack not installed

Install webpack to start bundling: 
  $ npm install --save-dev webpack
```

But if I type `webpack --version`, I get `4.43.0`.

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: is that in the same terminal? or is one iterm2 and one inside your ide?

Comment: @JoeLloyd Everything is in the same terminal

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you gave, your webpack.config.js might be invalid, e.g., importing missing module, or not exporting proper configuration.

See this issue for more context:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9242#issuecomment-500350448